# Automate exporting raster XMLs

Tags: arcpy, raster, rasterstats

I edit my raster catalogs to get a specific symbology and then I have to manually export the XML. I then load the XML into the mosaic dataset. I can't seem to find a way to automate the process of exporting all the XMLs and then importing them into the mosaics. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Also, I've looking into exporting the symbology to a layer and then pulling the stats from that but it failed. I almost thought the Create Referenced Mosaic Dataset tool was going to be exactly what I was looking for but that also was a dud.

Comment: What about the tool [Export XML Workspace Document](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/export-xml-workspace-document.htm)? Or is this not the same xml you are exporting?

Comment: @BERA No this is different. The symbology isn't saved like that from a raster catalog.

Comment: Could you explain how you export the xml?

Comment: I open up the properties of the raster catalog, open the Symoboloy tab, and I click the Export as XML button in the bottom of the window. It's when custom settings are used to set the statistics.